# I Use Generics, But Not This Class<T> thing!

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am trying to call [this method](http://linkee.com/cjNQ9m) to concat two arrays using Google Collections

```
public static <T> T[] concat(T[] first,
                             T[] second,
                             Class<T> type)
```

It's returning empty results. I am using

```
ObjectArrays.concat(array1, array2, Blah.class)
```

which is the only thing that compiles.

`array1` and `array2` are of type `Blah[]`.

What's the right syntax?

**Bonus question:** do other collections libraries have documentation with examples?

**Edit:** Problem was my bone-headed code.

```
public void register(ButtonPair[] pairs) {
    pairs = ObjectArrays.concat(this.pairs, pairs, ButtonPair.class);
}
```

the right side of the thing is okay, but the left side is **not** assigning to `this.pairs` due to the ambiguity. Sorry! And hats off to Google Collections!

Comment: Try Apache common collections, much better for your purpose check ArrayUtils

Comment: Any chance that you post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the failure?

Comment: Thanks @Teja Kantamneni, I will.

Comment: @BalusC, I just got pulled away so I cannot. However, if the syntax looks right to you, it may in fact be right :)

Comment: @BalusC, see the question for my update of why posting an SSCCE would've resulted in me seeing my error :) Thanks

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni, would you mind explaining why the Apache library is better?

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion, the documentation. I'm using your collection lib (Google's) and it's great and I don't doubt the implementation and API choices. But documentation, unlike code, does not need to be as tight as possible. An example or two IN THE API DOCS would be a friendly gesture. Apache Commons doesn't have great docs, but it's not as bad as your lib. Remind me if I'm missing some obvious docs, and no offense intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
String[] arr1 = { "abc", "def" };
String[] arr2 = { "ghi", "jkl" };
String[] result = ObjectArrays.concat(arr1, arr2, String.class);
```

How are you getting the result from concat()?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the result of the concat, but I must be messing something else up. I'll check my code. Thanks for that.

Comment: Marking this as best answer, because in fact I was, in a sense, not catching the return result. But I thought I was :) See the question

Answer (score 3):

For some example usage of the Google Collections classes, check out the [unit tests](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/#svn/trunk/test/com/google/common/collect%3Fstate%3Dclosed).

For [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/test/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArraysTest.java#101):

```
String[] result = ObjectArrays.concat(
    new String[] { "a", "b" }, new String[] { "c", "d" }, String.class);
assertEquals(String[].class, result.getClass());
assertContentsInOrder(Arrays.asList(result), "a", "b", "c", "d");
```

So, what the `Class<T>` notation means is that it needs you to specify what class the objects in the other two argument arrays belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks totally correct. I think the problem must be elsewhere. Are you 100% certain about the input values? Here is a test case:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;

public class ObjectArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] first = new String[] { "Fire", "Earth" };
        String[] second = new String[] { "Water", "Air" };

        String[] result = ObjectArrays.concat(first, second, String.class);

        for (String s : result)
        {
            System.out.println (s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, I see it must be elsewhere in my code. I thought I had bracketed the problem but I did not. Okay, last +1 for this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this because you are not assigning the result to the instance variable but to the method variable.

That is this:

```
public void register(ButtonPair[] pairs) {
    pairs = ObjectArrays.concat(this.pairs, pairs, ButtonPair.class);
    }
```

should be

```
public void register(ButtonPair[] pairs) {
    this.pairs = ObjectArrays.concat(this.pairs, pairs, ButtonPair.class);
    }
```

Incidentally, this is why at our shop we have have a different naming convention for method parameters and variables than that for instance variables (though not the awful prefixing/suffixing of instance variables like _someInstanceVar).

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, that is the problem. What's the naming convention you use?

Comment: We use full words for instance/class variables and 3 letter abbreviations for method parms and variables - it works really well for the most part, though occasionally a 3 letter word is what you want for the parm.